# Parsing input from file, delimiters, loops, java

Tags: java, parsing, file-io

The overall project is creating a system manager for airports.  It keeps track of airports, flights, seating sections, seats and other relevent info for each of those catagories.  The initial system is set up by importing from a file that's formatted a certain way.  I'm having problems parsing the file properly to set up the initial system.  the data is parsed from the file and used as method parameters to create the objects: Airport, Airline, Flight, FlightSection, and Seat.

the formatting is:
[list-of-airport-codes] {list-of-airlines}

list-of-airport-codes ::= comma-separated strings

list-of-airlines ::= airline-name1[flightinfo-list1], airline-name2[flightinfo-list2], airlinename3[flightinfo-list3], …

flightinfo-list ::= flightID1|flightdate1|originAirportCode1|destinationAirportCode1[flightsectionlist1], flightID2|flightdate2|originAirportCode2|destinationAirportCode2[flightsection-list2], …

flightdate ::= year, month, day-of-month, hours, minutes

flightsection-list ::= sectionclass: seat-price: layout: number-of-rows, …

sectionclass ::= F, B, E (for first class, business class, economy class)

layout ::= S, M, W (different known seating layouts)

example:

[DEN,NYC,SEA,LAX]{AMER[AA1|2018,10,8,16,30|DEN|LAX[E:200:S:4,F:500:S:2],
AA2|2018,8,9,7,30|LAX|DEN[E:200:S:5,F:500:S:3], …], UNTD[UA21|2018,11,8,12,30|NYC|SEA[E:300:S:6,F:800:S:3], UA12|2018,8,9,7,30|SEA|DEN[B:700:S:5, F:1200:S:2], …], FRONT[…], USAIR[…]}

I tried brute forcing it using a combination of delimiters and while loops.  The code successfully creates the Airports, first Airline and Flighsections, but when it gets to creating the second airline it crashes, because i'm not looping properly, and having a hard time getting it right.  My code for it as of now, is a mess, and if you're willing to look at it, I would appreciate any constructive input. My question is what would be a better way to approach this? A different design approach? Maybe a smarter way to use the delimiters?
Thanks in advance for your help!!

here's what i've tried.

```
private void readFile(File file){
    System.out.println("reading file");
    Scanner tempScan;
    String result;
    String temp = "";
    scan.useDelimiter("\\[|\\{"); 
    try{
        // AIRPORTS
        result = scan.next();
        tempScan = new Scanner(result);
        tempScan.useDelimiter(",|\\]");
        while(tempScan.hasNext()){
            temp = tempScan.next();
            sysMan.createAirport(temp);
        }
        tempScan.close();
        /* AIRLINE
         *    FLIGHT
         *    FLIGHTSECTION
         */
        do{
            // AIRLINE (loop<flight & fsection>)
            result = scan.next();
            sysMan.createAirline(result);
            // FLIGHT
            result = scan.next();
            tempScan = new Scanner(result);
            do{

                tempScan.useDelimiter(",|\\|");

                ArrayList flightInfo = new ArrayList();

                while(tempScan.hasNext()){
                    if(tempScan.hasNextInt()){
                        flightInfo.add(tempScan.nextInt());
                    } else {
                        flightInfo.add(tempScan.next());
                    }
                }

                tempScan.close();
                sysMan.createFlight(sysMan.getLastAddedAirline(),(String)flightInfo.get(0), (int)flightInfo.get(1), (int)flightInfo.get(2), (int)flightInfo.get(3), (int)flightInfo.get(4), (int)flightInfo.get(5), (String)flightInfo.get(6), (String)flightInfo.get(7));
                // FLIGHTSECTION (loop<itself>)
                result = scan.next();
                tempScan = new Scanner(result);
                tempScan.useDelimiter(",|:|\\]");
                ArrayList sectInfo = new ArrayList();

                int i = 1;
                while(!temp.contains("|")){
                    if(tempScan.hasNextInt()){
                        sectInfo.add(tempScan.nextInt());
                    } else {
                        temp = tempScan.next();
                        if(temp.equals(""))
                            break;
                        char c = temp.charAt(0);
                        sectInfo.add(c);
                    }
                    if(i == 4){
                        sysMan.createSection(sysMan.getLastAddedAirline(), sysMan.getLastAddedFlightID(), (char)sectInfo.get(0), (int)sectInfo.get(1), (char)sectInfo.get(2), (int)sectInfo.get(3));
                        i = 1;
                        sectInfo = null;
                        sectInfo = new ArrayList();
                        continue;
                    }

                    i++;
                }


            }while(!temp.equals("\\s+"));


        }while(!temp.contains("\\s+")); 




    }catch(NullPointerException e){
        System.err.println(e);
    }
}
```

Comment: Anything can be parsed but what you've written and are describing appears quite confusing. Take your provided example data **line** and show **exactly** how you would like each piece of string data to be parsed and into what variables.

Answer (score 0):

I'd rather chunk it down by regexp mathing the outer bounds, have a look, I took it a couple of levels broken.

```
import java.util.regex.Matcher;
```

import java.util.regex.Pattern;

public class Tokeni {

```
static String yolo = "[DEN,NYC,SEA,LAX]{AMER["
+ "AA1|2018,10,8,16,30|DEN|LAX[E:200:S:4,F:500:S:2],"
+ "AA2|2018,8,9,7,30|LAX|DEN[E:200:S:5,F:500:S:3]],"
+ "UNTD[UA21|2018,11,8,12,30|NYC|SEA[E:300:S:6,F:800:S:3],"
+ "UA12|2018,8,9,7,30|SEA|DEN[B:700:S:5, F:1200:S:2]]}";

public static void main(String[] args) {

    Matcher airportCodesMatcher = Pattern.compile("\\[(.*?)\\]").matcher(yolo);
    airportCodesMatcher.find();
    String[] airportCodes = airportCodesMatcher.group(1).split(",");

    Matcher airLinesMatcher = Pattern.compile("\\{(.*?)\\}").matcher(yolo);
    airLinesMatcher.find();
    String airLinesStr = airLinesMatcher.group(1);

    System.out.println(airLinesStr);

    Pattern airLinePattern = Pattern.compile("\\D+\\[(.*?)\\]\\]");
    Matcher airLineMatcher = airLinePattern.matcher(airLinesStr);

    while( airLineMatcher.find() ) {
        String airLineStr = airLineMatcher.group(0).trim();
        if(airLineStr.startsWith(",")) {
            airLineStr = airLineStr.substring(1, airLineStr.length()).trim();
        }           

        System.out.println(airLineStr);

        Matcher airLineNameMatcher = Pattern.compile("[A-Z]+").matcher(airLineStr);
        airLineNameMatcher.find();
        String airLineName = airLineNameMatcher.group(0).trim();
        System.out.println(airLineName);

        airLineStr = airLineStr.substring(airLineStr.indexOf("[")+1, airLineStr.length());          
        Matcher airLineInfoMatcher = Pattern.compile("\\D+(.*?)\\]").matcher(airLineStr);   
        while(airLineInfoMatcher.find()) {
            String airLineInfoStr = airLineInfoMatcher.group(0).trim();
            if(airLineInfoStr.startsWith(",")) {
                airLineInfoStr = airLineInfoStr.substring(1, airLineInfoStr.length()).trim();
            }               
            System.out.println(airLineInfoStr);
        }           
    }       
}
```

}